# Curved 'A' character in math mode

Tags: math-mode, symbols, characters

I'm looking for a way to write more or less the following character in math mode (it'a a sort of omega with a bar):

[image]

How can I do it?

Comment: So you don't want a bar over an Omega?

Comment: Hello @egreg, I need the symbol in the figure, the bar is in the middle of "omega"...of course it's not a real omega so you can suggest also other symbols more or less similar to the one above. I changed a little bit the image, there was an imperfection

Comment: You are not just looking for `\mathscr{A}` or `\mathcal{A}`?

Comment: Thank you @md2perpe it's great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found `\Lbag` and `\Rbag` in `stmaryrd`; reflecting a reduced version of them, joining them at the top and adding the bar yields

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gaA}{} % for safety
\DeclareRobustCommand{\gaA}{\mathpalette\gaA@\relax}
\newcommand{\gaA@}[2]{%
  \vphantom{X}%
  \ooalign{$\m@th#1\relbar$\cr\hidewidth\gaA@@{#1}\hidewidth\cr}%
}
\newcommand{\gaA@@}[1]{%
  \raisebox{\depth}{\scalebox{0.75}[-0.75]{$\m@th#1\Lbag\gaA@kern{#1}\Rbag$}}%
}
\newcommand{\gaA@kern}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle \mkern-2.2mu \else
  \ifx#1\textstyle \mkern-2.2mu \else
  \ifx#1\scriptstyle \mkern-2.6mu \else
  \mkern-3.3mu \fi\fi\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A+\gaA+B$

$\scriptstyle A+\gaA+B$

$\scriptscriptstyle A+\gaA+B$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @egreg thank you very much for your answer. If possible, I'd like to ask you to search also a curved 'A' character

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi I skimmed over a font catalogue, but couldn’t find anything suitable

Comment: ok thank you anyway

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple stab at something similar: a minus sign overlaid upon an `\Omega`.

If you are willing to horizontally shrink the minus, you can get this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\baromega{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{\stackengine
  {0pt}{\SavedStyle\Omega}{\SavedStyle\hstretch{.7}{-}}%
  {O}{c}{F}{T}{L}}}}
\begin{document}
$\baromega\scriptstyle\baromega\scriptscriptstyle\baromega$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you just want to stick with the normal minus width, here is what it looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\baromega{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{\stackengine
  {0pt}{\SavedStyle\Omega}{\SavedStyle-}%
  {O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}}}
\begin{document}
$\baromega\scriptstyle\baromega\scriptscriptstyle\baromega$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, it is very font dependent.  Here it is with `\newtxmath` loaded:

[image]